# OOP : Name Error while trying to make a object instance

Tags: python-3.x, oop, python-import

I have a class called FIT, saved in a file called manage. 
in my main file, the first lines look like this

```
import manage

FITobj= FIT()
```

I thought when I did this it would call the class so I would be able to use functions like `get_balance()` like `FITobj.get_balance()`. but instead, when I try to run my program I get `name error name FIT is not defined`. I'm fairly new to object-oriented programming, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate where the `FIT` class is defined. Either change it to:

```
import manage
FITobj = manage.FIT()
```

Or

```
from manage import FIT
FITobj = FIT()
```

The first is slightly more typing, but it helps keep your code more readable because as you import more and more, it can get very difficult to keep track of where everything is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @mypetlion's answer, to avoid even more typing (but make your program even less readable), you can do this:

```
from manage import *
FITobj=FIT()
```

And then use **anything else** from `manage` as well as just `FIT`.